# c# how to count in datatable between specified time

Tags: c#, winforms, search, datatable

I have a data table, and would like to count the NR 1 is how many times was registered between Time 6-14:

example:

```
NAME   FABRIKNR   DATE           TIME
abc     1       24.04.2017    06:00:00
abc     2       24.04.2017    08:00:00
abc     3       24.04.2017    10:00:00
abc     1       24.04.2017    11:00:00
abc     2       24.04.2017    11:10:00
abc     3       24.04.2017    14:20:00
abc     1       24.04.2017    19:00:00
abc     2       24.04.2017    22:00:00
abc     3       24.04.2017    22:00:00
```

I started to calculate with the Date.Time seconds and with break times but i think it is a wrong way.

I can count the Fabrik Nr 1 and it works:

```
  foreach (string text_line in raw_text)
        {


            data_col = text_line.Split(';');

            //header
            if (x == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= data_col.Count() - 1; i++)
                {
                    dgv_table.Columns.Add(data_col[i]);
                }
                x++;
            }

            else
            {
                //data
                dgv_table.Rows.Add(data_col);
            }
            // timer1.Start();
        }

        DataRow[] rowCount = dgv_table.Select("FABRIKNR = '1'");
        this.lb_qty.Text = rowCount.Length.ToString();

        NrOfCycles = lb_qty.Text;
```

I think i have to check the time range
DataRow[] rowCount = dgv_table.Select("FABRIKNR = '1' AND TIME >= '06:00:00'  AND TIME < '14:00:00'");

But something is wrong the program stops on reading and don't give any error(no freeze).

Can anyone help me in search?
And the result is... :) pabammm...

```
  DataRow[] rowCount = dgv_table.Select("FABRIKNR = '1' AND (TIME >= '6:00:00')and (TIME < '14:00:00') ");
   DataRow[] rowCount = dgv_table.Select("FABRIKNR = '1' AND (TIME >= '14:00:00')and (TIME < '22:00:00') ");
```

Comment: DataRow[] rowCount = dgv_table.Select("FABRIKNR = '1'AND TIME => '06:00:00' TIME < '14:00:00'""); should be  DataRow[] rowCount = dgv_table.Select("FABRIKNR = '1'AND TIME => '06:00:00' TIME < '14:00:00' ")

Comment: Dear Wai, Yes You have right it was only mistake on copied data in program was correct. i edited. Thanks! The problem not changed!

Comment: "FABRIKNR = '1' AND TIME => '06:00:00' AND TIME  < '14:00:00'" also the AND should be before te last TIME

Comment: You mean `"FABRIKNR = '1' AND TIME => '06:00:00' AND TIME < '14:00:00' "`

Comment: OmG i see it looks a im tired but after i modified for that the result is the same. No result in counting :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your select query. Change it to the following:

```
DataRow[] rowCount = dgv_table.Select("FABRIKNR = '1' AND TIME >= '06:00:00' AND TIME < '14:00:00'");
```

`TIME` and `AND` where flipped. Also, `TIME` should be `>=` or `>` than your starting time and `<` or `<=` to your ending time.

Comment: i modified for that the result is the same. No result in counting :(

Comment: See Stephen Bauer's answer below also. I'll edit above to reflect what he noticed as well.

Answer (score 1):

There's another typo, it should be `>=` instead of `=>`:

```
DataRow[] rowCount = dgv_table.Select("FABRIKNR = '1' AND TIME >= '06:00:00'  AND TIME < '14:00:00'");
```

Comment: Oh my god i think i am very very tired.. guys sorry :(

Comment: "FABRIKNR = '1' AND ZEIT >= '6:00:00' AND ZEIT < '14:00:00' " gives back zero because it (time now 12:00 ) is in the future. Than i could not search smaller than? If yes then how? Thx a lot!

Comment: iS THE COLUMN NAME `ZEIT` correct or should it be `TIME`? The current time should not matter when querying the table...

Comment: ZEIT, TIME  yes it is correct  (one of it is started on German file :)). This combined search is not working well.. i don't know how to step forward.

Comment: There is now no data which starts 14:00:00

Comment: As long as there is at least one row that starts at or after 06:00:00, everything should be fine, even if there is no data with 14:00:00 or later